# Unable to specify custom error in jQuery validation engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am fiddling with the jQuery validation engine documented [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

I have downloaded all JS files locally. And created a simple form with single required textbox field.

**Problem 1**

I am unable to specify custom error for this required rule (even though I have specified custom-error-message option). Instead it shows the default message "This field is required." I have written this code with the help of example (shown [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#custom_error_messages)) on the git, but it is not working. Please point out where it is going wrong. (I want to do it with JS object literals instead of using equivalent html5 attributes.)

My code:

```
<html>
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js"> </script>      
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="styles/validationEngine.jquery.css"  />   
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#form1").validationEngine({'custom_error_messages' : {                                
                            '#username':{
                                'required':{
                                    'message':"Hey you cannot leave this field blank."
                                }
                            }     
                        }
                    });                         
                });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <br /><br />
        <h2>Form 1</h2>
        Username: <input id="#username" type="text" class="validate[required]" ></input> <br />     
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem 2**

How can I specify what rule to apply to which element in JS instead of specifying class values in html. I will prefer to have clean unobtrusive html instead of mixing validation specific stuff in html. This is possible with [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) as follows:

```
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    agree: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    agree: "Please accept our policy"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
```

Is this possible with the jQuery Validation engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it is possible : [link](https://github.com/karol-gontarski/jQuery-Validation-Engine#standard-html5-attribute-for-error-message)

exemple :

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-validation-engine="validate[required,custom[email]]"
    data-errormessage-value-missing="Email is required!" 
    data-errormessage-custom-error="Let me give you a hint: someone@nowhere.com" 
    data-errormessage="This is the fall-back error message."/>
```

Also please note that since JQuery 1.9 many functions that worked in past version are now removed or deprecated and a fix was added tree days ago, so you might want to download the latest version : [jQuery.validationEngine v2.6.1](https://github.com/karol-gontarski/jQuery-Validation-Engine.git)

**edit**
don' t know if they corrected it yet but in the .js file replace

```
line28 : .live(...
```

by

```
line 28 : .on(...
```

live has been removed since jQuery 1.9

**edit:**

you did a small mistake :

```
<input id="**#**username" type="text" class="validate[required]" ></input> <br />
```

the **#** should be there :

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="validate[required]" ></input> <br/>
```

Comment: few more points: 
* I dont want to use html5 attributes
* I dont want any validation stuff in html, just ids and name
* I want to do it with JS Object Literals, so I will like if I understand what is going wrong with my JS

I have edited problem 1 description a bit, please read.

Comment: well actually the js uses the attibutes to generate the messages. So what you want to do is have it in the script. Let me check the code for you it seems ok.

Comment: just remove the # in the id field.

Comment: but where is that `line28 : .live(...` which JS file?

Comment: it was corected. JqueryvalidationEngine.js